# Weird Rspec Behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec2

I am using Rspec and no matter if I run it with rspec spec, guard, or auto test I get the following behavior. I ran these commands one right after another by pushing up arrow and hitting enter. I didn't time them, but I know they weren't taking a minute to execute. Maybe three seconds at most. Is this a known bug?

```
Finished in 27.13 seconds
17 examples, 0 failures
[sample_app (master)]$ rspec spec
.................

Finished in 55.46 seconds
17 examples, 0 failures
[sample_app (master)]$ rspec spec
.................

Finished in 61.27 seconds
17 examples, 0 failures
[sample_app (master)]$ rspec spec
.................

Finished in 65.56 seconds
17 examples, 0 failures
[sample_app (master)]$
```

Comment: Everything fine here even on a big and slow specs.

Comment: Everything is working fine, but is annoying that the times aren't right. I get 5000 seconds sometimes, but I think it is counting from the last time it ran in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what causing this result. I had `--drb` in my .rspec file.